# How do I show that the forgetful functor $F : \text {Grp} \rightarrow \text {Set} $ is co-representable?

Tags: category-theory, set-theory, functors, representable-functor

Let $F : \text {Grp} \rightarrow \text {Set} $ be the forgetful functor. I am trying to show that $F$ is co-representable

My definition of co-representability reads:

A functor $F:  C \rightarrow \text{Set}$ is called co-representable if there exists an object $Y\in C$ with $ h^Y:=\operatorname {Hom}_C(Y,-) \cong  F$. How do I continue form here? I guess I need to construct an explicit isomorphism but I am not sure how

Comment: Welcome to mse! What have you tried? Do you have any ideas of your own? Once we have a better idea of exactly where you're struggling, we can help you better ^_^

Comment: @HallaSurvivor Thanks, actually I don't know how to approach it, other than writing the definition of isomorphism of functors for those 2 particular functors,which is what I am trying to get to. Some hints on how to start and what path to follow should be useful

Comment: The representing object is $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan How did you arrive to that conclusion?

Comment: This is very standard stuff. More generally in a category of algebraic [thing]s the representing object of the forgetful functor is the free [thing] on one generator. The real question is how should *you* arrive at this conclusion; write down carefully what a homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}$ to another group is.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan is $\Bbb Z$ also the co-representing object? Or did you actually meant co-representing?

Comment: I mean what you're calling co-representing but many people just call this "representing." Any particular functor is either covariant or contravariant, so there's no ambiguity here.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, would it suffice to prove that the map $\text{Hom}(\Bbb Z, G) \rightarrow G: f \mapsto f(1)$ is injective?

Comment: It would suffice to prove that that map is *bijective*.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, $\mathbb{Z}$ is the "co-representing" object. You want to prove that $Hom(\mathbb{Z}, - ) \cong F$; thus, you need to find a natural isomorphism between the two functors. This means that, for each object $G \in Grp$, you want to find a $Set$-isomorphism (i.e. a bijection) $$\eta_G : Hom(\mathbb{Z},G) \to G$$ such that for every group homomorphism $f : G \to X$ we have $$\eta_H \circ Hom(\mathbb{Z},f) = F(f) \circ \eta_G$$
As you pointed out, for each $G \in Grp$, the definition of $\eta_G$ should be $\eta_G(f) = f(1)$ for every $f \in Hom(\mathbb{Z},G)$. It's easy to see that, for every $G$, this map is a bijection (every morphism from $\mathbb{Z}$ is determined by where it sends $1$ and every $g \in G$ is a good choice).
To check naturality: First note that, for each $f : G \to H$, $F(f) = f$ and $Hom(\mathbb{Z},f) = f \circ -$. Now, it's easy to check that
$$\forall g \in Hom(\mathbb{Z},G) \quad (f\circ \eta_G)(g) = (\eta_H \circ (f \circ -))(g) $$

Comment: Nice to see you back here, M.B.! :)